# Minecraft Server Paused after my Custom Plugin Loading

Tags: server, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

this problem has started after I fixed my Plugin in the maven file with erasing this.

```
<outputDirectory>D:\My New Plugins\Server\plugins</outputDirectory>
```

this breaked my first test Server erasing all the Plugin Folder Files and damaged the code. Then after reopening the server, the server always stops at this part:
[image]

Which I was worried considering my Plugin is broken. Do I have to make a new Plugin and transfer most of the files?

Note: the Last Yellow Lines in the picture Indicate the Use of the JScoreboard dependency used in my plugin. Thanks.

Edit: There is also a warning in the build log:

> maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
> present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
> single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
> Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
> otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
> mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
> See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

This might be Related.

Comment: Can you show your code and you plugin.yml file ?

Comment: [Don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3750257)

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be JScoreBoards. It does not support Minecraft version 1.18, and therefore is unable to load up properly.